# Conveyor Belt Pattern?

Tags: java, oop, xslt, design-patterns, jaxb

The project I'm currently working on is a web application (mostly Web Services, not JSP or anything like that) which functions as a 'façade' between an older interface coming from the front (a web page it exposes a couple of web services to) and a more complex interface at the bottom (using web services to call them).

A lot of the web services at the bottom have quite complex structures (part of a standard I can't change).

What I like to do in cases like that, is create simple JAXB POJOs and use XSLT to convert them to their complex structures.

For example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "simplequery", namespace="http://www.foo.com")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SimpleQuery {

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String name;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And I can call it like this:

```
SimpleQuery sq = new SimpleQuery();
sq.setId("12264736376374");
org.w3c.dom.Document sqDoc = new XsltTransformer("SimpleQuery-to-VeryComplexQuery.xsl").transform();
QueryConsumer.sendQuery(sqDoc);
```

You'll just have to assume those classes exist and do what you think they do.

Here's a relevant snippet from my example XSLT:

```
<template match="foo:simplequery">
    <some><complex><structure><id><x:value-of select="foo:id"/></id></structure></complex></some>
</template>
```

I like doing it like this for 2 reasons:

1. The "configuration" is done in XSLT and not in compiled code so I can easily maintain it
2. I don't have to create horrible (what I like to call) "pyramid code" like this with a complex JAXB object:

   `Some s = new Some();
    s.setComplex(new Complex());
    s.getComplex().setStructure(new Structure());
    s.getComplex().getStructure().setId(new Id());
    s.getComplex().getStructure().getId().setValue("1222333232");`

Time to get to the point. There are a couple of complex interfaces pointing to different web services and even servers, all in their respective namespaces.

During some refactoring OCD I want to place this part:

```
SimpleQuery sq = new SimpleQuery();
sq.setId("12264736376374");
org.w3c.dom.Document sqDoc = new XsltTransformer("SimpleQuery-to-VeryComplexQuery.xsl").transform();
```

...into a specific static class with a static method.

**Now the challenge: Find a good name for that class!**

What the class does is very simple: It takes a simplified object and converts it to the complex object. Hence, my `Conveyor Belt` pattern. In this case, it just spits out DOM Documents, but it could potentially also create JAXB objects which are JAXB'd versions of that Document (my XsltTransformer can already do this).

I tried a name like `ComplexQueryFactory`, but it just didn't seem right.